# mysql query group by in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following query:

```
SELECT files.file_name, files.locked, projects.project_name, 
group_concat( versions.version, versions.language SEPARATOR ' & ')
FROM    files
JOIN `projects` ON (files.project_id = projects.project_id) 
JOIN `versions` ON (files.file_id = versions.file_id)
WHERE   files.file_id = '1'
ORDER BY projects.project_name ASC
```

this gives me this table:

```
filename - 1 - projectname - 0.1EN & 0.2FR & 0.3DE & 0.1IT
```

what i want, is the query to output something like this:

```
filename - 1 - projectname - 0.1-EN,IT & 0.2-FR & 0.3-DE
```

so i tried this:

```
group_concat( versions.version, versions.language GROUP BY versions.version SEPARATOR ' & ')
```

but mysql did not like that.
How can i get the result i want? Thanks.

Edit: sample tables!
[image: files table]
[image: projects table]
[image: versions table]

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: you mean give sample tables that the query pulls data from?

Comment: yes `:D` if it is ok with you.

Comment: see pics in edit: top: files table, right: projects table, bottom left: versions table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT  a.file_name,
        a.locked,
        b.project_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.version, c.language SEPARATOR ' & ')
FROM    files a
        INNER JOIN projects b
            ON a.project_id = b.project_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  file_ID, `version`, GROUP_CONCAT(language) language
            FROM    versions
            GROUP   BY file_ID, `version`
        ) c ON  a.file_ID = c.file_ID
WHERE   a.file_ID = 1
GROUP   BY  a.file_name,
            a.locked,
            b.project_name
```

Comment: J W@: I believe it should be `GROUP BY file_ID, version` , not just by `file_ID` in subquery.

Comment: mmh, the group_concat outputs: `0.1EN,FR,DE,IT`

Comment: Great, thanks, how can i add `-` between the output like: `0.1-EN,IT & 0.2-FR & 0.3-DE` ?

Comment: is this what you mean? `GROUP_CONCAT(c.version, ' - ',c.language SEPARATOR ' & ')`